# How do I create space between youtube videos in my webpage? I am using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I used below code.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bpdpl4FjkjM?list=UU1H37OGfdt7JZzJJ4jS-bhA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>                               
</div>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 ">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i6wVUyol7W4?list=UU1H37OGfdt7JZzJJ4jS-bhA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a padding between the divs to simulate a gap might be a hack, but why not use something Bootstrap provides. It's called offsets. But again, you can define a class in your custom.css (you shouldn't edit the core stylesheet anyway) file and add something like .gap. However, .col-md-offset-* does the job most of the times for me, allowing me to precisely leave a gap between the divs.

As for vertical spacing, unfortunately, there isn't anything set built-in like that in Bootstrap 3, so you will have to invent your own custom class to do that. I'd usually do something like .top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }. This does the trick, and obviously, it doesn't have to be 20px, it can be anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Bootstrap 3, so there is no built-in utility classes to add vertical spacing. You can add spaces using css:

```
.embed-responsive {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

or only between embed video blocks only:

```
.embed-responsive + .embed-responsive {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.embed-responsive{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.